# Remove separator line for only one cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to remove the separator for one `UITableViewCell`. I did the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.row == 1)
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    return cell;
}
```

(It's `static cells`.) When I run the app. The separator line is still there. How can I remove the separator line for one `cell`?

Comment: Setting separatorInset to UIEdgeInsetsZero is to show the separator the with from the left to right. Do you want to hide the separatorInset only at the row index 1?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to hide the separator at row index 1

Comment: removing only 1 separator on the cell is tricky because you either get all seperator inset or none. I usually ended up implement my own separator view that is just a uiview with 1 pixel height. Then, design to show and hide the separator view. There may be some better ideas. which Im keen to learn us well.

Comment: Can you please provide an example. Also In the storyboard, should I set separator to none?

Comment: Yes. if you want to have a custom separator view, you need to set separator to none. For the example, it will take a while to write it up. If you could wait, i'll try to put thing together roughly.

Comment: I posted code as an answer. hope it help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

On iOS 8 you need to use:

```
cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
```

If you want to be compatible with iOS 7 as well you should do following:

```
if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
    [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}

if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
    [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
```

**ADD:** If previous didn't work - use this. (from answer below)

```
 cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX, 0, 0);
```

If none of above worked, you can do:

`self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

but this will leave 1 pixel empty space, not really removing a line, more making it transparent.

Comment: Will the second method support ios 8 as well?

Comment: first one is for iOS 7 and lower, second one is for iOS 8. You need to put both into your app, so it will run proper code for given iOS version

Comment: (In the answer you wrote the first one is for io8.) Do I need to have an if statement to support both versions?

Comment: respondsToSelector takes care of checking if the method exists, which is compatibility check

Comment: you should use UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX, 0, 0);

Comment: None of these solutions have any effect in my case

Comment: @luciusdegeer self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor]; should solve your problem

Answer (score 20):

You can just visually hide separator through `separatorInset` property:

```
tableViewCell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10000, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Answer (score 15):

### Swift 4

#### iOS 11

Assign next values for specific cell you need for customization.

```
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
cell.directionalLayoutMargins = .zero
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to hide the separation line for only a specific type of cell, you can use the following code:

```
 override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    subviews.forEach { (view) in
        if view.dynamicType.description() == "_UITableViewCellSeparatorView" {
            view.hidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

Write this code in the cell (it must be a subclass of `UITableViewCell`) for which you do not want a separation line to appear.

Comment: I tried a bunch of other solutions and this ended up being the least hacky. In Swift 3.0, this is the correct syntax:
`subviews.forEach { view in
    if type(of: view).description() == "_UITableViewCellSeparatorView" {
        view.isHidden = true
    }
}`

Comment: Hackiest of the solutions.

Comment: Warning - this causes issues in iOS 10. iOS seems to clone separator properties between cell instances, and completely different cell classes on different tableviews start appearing with no separator.

Comment: This is very hacky and will probably break in a future release of iOS.

Comment: This is using a private API, and even if it works, there is a risk that your application will be rejected

Answer (score 5):

Swift 5  Enjoy

```
//MARK:- In which row you want to hide 
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, bottom: 0, right: 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add following to the cell you don't want separator (swift 3) :

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    // remove separator
    self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 1000, 0, 0)
}
```

Comment: This seems to be hack..but not recommended to for ideal programming.

Answer (score 1):

For those people struggling with this for iOS 9 the solution is a little different than the answers already given. Here is how I solved it in Swift:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    table.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if IS_THE_CELL_WITH_NO_SEPARATOR{
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if IS_THE_CELL_WITH_NO_SEPARATOR{
        let size = self.view.bounds.size
        let rightInset = size.width > size.height ? size.width : size.height
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, rightInset)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0 , cell.bounds.size.width , 0.0, -cell.bounds.size.width)
```

Comment: Although this may answer the question, some context and/or explanation would be nice. For future readers also.

Answer (score 1):

I created a Extension to UITableViewCell, setting separatorInset value brings anchor bugs to me, I'm using Eureka form Pod.

```
extension UITableViewCell {
    func hideSeparator(hide: Bool) {
        let subviews = self.subviews
        for view in subviews {
            if view.classForCoder.description() == "_UITableViewCellSeparatorView" {
                view.isHidden = hide
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way that is a bit hacky is to create the custom table view cell with a uiView that acts like separator inset. Then, hide and show that when you want to.

I created SampleTableViewCell and a nib file with label and separatorLineView

```
@interface SampleTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *separatorLineView;
@end
```

Then, in ViewController Class

```
@interface ViewController () 
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *items;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.items = @[@"A", @"B", @"C"];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SampleTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SampleCell"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    SampleTableViewCell *cell = (SampleTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SampleCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.titleLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row];
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        cell.separatorLineView.hidden = YES;
    } else {
        cell.separatorLineView.hidden = NO;
    }
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.1 -

```
override public func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    subviews.forEach { (view) in
        if type(of: view).description() == "_UITableViewCellSeparatorView" {
            view.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a good idea. Accessing a private API could get your app disapproved. This name could also change in the future without you knowing.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to show separator to only the visible cell you can try this:

```
tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 1000, bottom: 0, right: 0)

let visibleCell = tableView.visibleCells

    for cellV in visibleCell{
        cellV.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Make `UITableView` style is `.plain`

use below line of code in

```
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
```

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`
method

Answer (score -16):

Swift 3 remove separator all cell:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.yourTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none
    }
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer]. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995)

Comment: More importantly, this answer doesn't answer the question asked. This code simply disables the separators on the entire table; not selectively on a single cell at a time.

Comment: this code simply removes all separators from all cells on the entire tableView
the answer is not correct.